# To compute $P(min\left \{ X_{1}, X_{2}\right \} \ge 5)$ for two iid discrete distributed random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, discrete-data

Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be two independent and identically distributed random variables with the probability mass function as :

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^x & \text{ if } x=1,2,... \\ 
0 & \text{ otherwise }  
\end{cases}$

Then, We are required to compute $P(min\left \{ X_{1}, X_{2}\right \} \ge 5)$.

I have tried to solve this problem using two different approaches.

**Approach.1**

$P(min\left \{ X_{1}, X_{2}\right \} \ge 5) = P(X_{1} \ge 5)P(X_{2} \ge 5) $.

This gave me the correct answer but I doubt what I did wrong in the second approach.

**Approach.2**

Let $Z = min(X_{1}, X_{2})$

$P(Z = z) = P(min(X_{1}, X_{2}) = z) = P(X_{1} = z, X_{2} \ge z) + P(X_{1} \ge z, X_{2} = z) = 2P(X_{1} = z, X_{2} \ge z) = 4(\frac{1}{4})^x$

Now, P(Z) should be a pmf of Z. But when I sum, it is not giving me 1.

What am I missing here? Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In approach 2 you have incorrectly included the probability of $X_1=z\cap X_2=z$ twice rather than once.

Comment: Thank you so much @JarleTufto. I was frustrated since morning on this problem.